# Different number of replacement and data rows after diff() applied to list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, for-loop, diff

I have a list of 993 elements, each element consisting of seven variables with differing numbers of observations. This list was created by splitting a dataframe.

I need to apply the diff() function to one of the variables within the elements. However, when I attempt,  R gives me the following error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DiffINT", value = c(1.02, 0, 0, 0,  : replacement has 30 rows, data has 34

The following is the loop that I am using.

```
 for (i in 1:993){
   ONT.list[[i]][["DiffINT"]] <- diff(ONT.list[[i]][["INTprice"]], lag = 4)
 }
```

The DiffINT variable contains as many rows as the rest of the variables in the element, and is currently filled with NA's. My objective is to leave the first 4 NA's in there, as the data should be lagged.

Any suggestions for how to get around this error or manipulate the elements in the list more efficiently are welcome. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks to the commenters for their help, adding the 4 NA's worked! 
But in the loop continuing, a new problem arose: when the row length is less than 4.

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DiffINT", value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
>     replacement has 4 rows, data has 2

Suggestions?

EDIT2:

Got it. Added an if statement.

```
 for (i in 1:993) {
   if (length(ONT.list[[i]][["INTprice"]]) >= 4)
   ONT.list[[i]][["DiffINT"]] <- c(rep(NA,4),diff(ONT.list[[i]]
   [["INTprice"]], lag = 4))
 }
```

Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: What is the length of `diff(1:3)`?

Comment: And of `diff(1:5, lag = 4)`?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your questions, but running length() with your requests returns 2 (for 1:3) and 1 (for 1:5, lag = 4).

Comment: @ZuzannaJurewicz I think you should change as `ONT.list[[i]][["DiffINT"]] <- c(rep(NA,4),diff(ONT.list[[i]][["INTprice"]], lag = 4)`

Comment: I think what @Rui was trying to get at was that it looks like you're replacing a vector with a shorter vector (`diff` function returns a shorter vector). So you'll likely need to pad the replacement with `NA`s (see @MKR's suggestion)

Comment: @zack yes, that's exactly what I meant, MKR does what I believed would become obvious to the OP. But like many times over, "obvious" is not at all the same to everybody.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Please see the edit for a new issue. 
@RuiBarradas Indeed. Conceptually it was obvious, but my R skills are severely lacking so implementation was tougher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following solves this last error you are getting.
Please note that what is important in this answer is the loop, not the exact data structure.

```
set.seed(1234)    # make the results reproducible
ONT.list <- list(data.frame(INTprice = rnorm(2)),
                 data.frame(INTprice = rnorm(4)),
                 data.frame(INTprice = rnorm(5)),
                 data.frame(INTprice = rnorm(20))
)

for(i in seq_along(ONT.list)){
  n <- nrow(ONT.list[[i]])
  d <- diff(ONT.list[[i]][["INTprice"]], lag = 4)
  ONT.list[[i]][["DiffInt"]] <- c(rep(NA, pmin.int(4, n - length(d))), d)
}

ONT.list
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have the code added in EDIT2 above, but I will definitely adapt yours for other things I need to do. Thanks for taking the time to write it out for me!